# I want to Deactivate the Apex Trigger using Apex

Tags: community

I have created a trigger using HTTP request. Now I need to inactive the trigger. I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can deactivate it the same way we deploy, just change the metadata file status to Inactive

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexTrigger xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>33.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Inactive</status>
</ApexTrigger>
```

Other way is, you can create a list custom setting to set inactive triggers.

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {
    if (Inactive_Triggers__c.getInstance('AccountTrigger') != null) return;
    ....
}
```

You can insert, delete inactive trigger custom settings from your VF page.

Comment: Yes I know this way. I having a different problem. I have created a vf page from which I create ApexTrigger. Now I want to Edit or Inactive the trigger from the Vf page.

Comment: @AshishVaishnav If you've defined switches for these triggers using some static variable to custom settings then you can simply change those settings.

Comment: Yes Rohit, using switches I can do. thanks. Also, I need to edit the trigger. means Edit the logic part. So, Is there any way to  edit trigger Dynamically

Comment: @Rahul, Yes for Inactivating I can use this. I also need to update the trigger code.

Comment: @AshishVaishnav Not sure if this is possible. Ideally developers directly edit code by going to Apex classes and triggers.

Comment: @AshishVaishnav You need to edit or make a callout to deactivate it. if the number is not so big, there should not be an issue to edit them and deploy in one go. how many triggers you have?

Comment: Okay Thanks, @RohitMourya for your help. If you got any solution related to this that How can we update trigger code dynamically then please let me know.

Comment: @rahulgawale Actually, It is only one trigger at a time. My visualforce Page giving functionality to Create, Inactive or Edit trigger. I am creating a trigger using an HTTP POST request. But I getting problem in Inactivating or Edit the Trigger.

Comment: I mean how many triggers you need to edit if you go with the "switch" option?

Comment: Actually, with the Switch option, there can be many triggers. But If we talk about Editing the Trigger logic there will be only one trigger at a time

Comment: Then you can easily go with the switch option, right?

Comment: Yes I will use switch option for Deactivating, but right now i'm asking for Editing the Trigger logic

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the Metadata API to make changes to trigger metadata. This is done by the open-source package [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), which could provide an example. There is a [wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) for the Metadata API in Apex.

Before embarking on this project, there's a few considerations to take into account.

- You're still responsible for ensuring test coverage in production for all deployments. Activating and deactivating triggers are deployment operations. If you fail to secure sufficient code coverage, your deployments will fail.
- The user running your code must have sufficient permission to talk to the Metadata API.
- Dynamically making changes to a running production org's metadata is a high-risk strategy. You should exhaust all other architectural options before doing so.
- Many orgs will see this (correctly) as a security risk.